# How do i remove a command message in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to delete the command message (the one sent by the user not by bot)
Ive tried it like this.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("-"):
        wait(5)
        await message.delete()
```

and this

```
@bot.command()
async def creator(ctx, message):
    await ctx.send(f"Example text")
    wait(5)
    await message.delete()
```

but none of them work. If you know why please post a solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should use `await ctx.message.delete()` in a command. The `wait` method doesn't exist, instead you should use `asyncio.sleep(5)`.

Answer (score -1):

In the first code :

```
import time
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot : return
    if message.content.startswith("-"):
        time.sleep(5)
        await message.delete()
```

Second Code

```
import time
@bot.command()
async def creator(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Example text")
    time.sleep(5)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

If you are using the both of `on_message` and `commands` in your bot,
You may want to add this in the end of `on_message` Event So your bot will handle the `on_message` event, Then it goes to process commands.
Without it the bot commands wont work .

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Eg :

```
@bot.event 
async def on_message(message) :
    await message.channel.send("Example")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: There is almost never a use case for `time.sleep` in discord.py programming, `asyncio.sleep` should always be used.

Comment: Agreed, But the purpose of the answer was the delete, not the delay .